# Undefined offset issue in explode

Tags: php, csv, explode

Firstly I apologise for asking a question which must be somewhat rookie or simple, but I cannot seem to find any code that I've researched to solve my problem.

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\Assignment\Table.php on line 14

This error continues from Offset 1 - 7.

The code that I am currently using to pull the data from the CSV file is as follows:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen ("quotes.csv","r");
if (!$fp) {echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.</p>"; exit;}
?>
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Volume </th></tr>
<?php

$i=0;
while (!feof($fp)):
   $line = fgets($fp, 2048);
   $out[$i] = array($line);

   list ($ID, $Price, $StockDate, $StockTime, $Change, $DayHI, $DayLOW, $Volume,) = explode(",", $out[$i][0]);


   echo "<tr><td>$ID</td> <td>$Price</td> <td>$StockDate </td><td>$StockTime</td> <td>$Change</td> <td>$DayHI</td> <td>$DayLOW</td> <td>$Volume</td></tr>";
   $fp++;
   $i++;
endwhile;

?>
</table>
<?php


//echo "<p>".$out[0][0]."</p>";
//echo "<p>".$out[1][0]."</p>";
//echo "<p>".$out[2][0]."</p>";
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I'm unsure as to how something is undefined as the correct number of values are being called from the CSV.

I understand this isn't a site to teach someone PHP basics but any advice would be appreciated to help solve the problem, I would be appreciative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't want to +1 on file pointer:

```
$fp++;
```

Removing this line should do the trick.

**UPDATE**:

You should also check [fgets](http://www.php.net/fgets) if it's not false, because it means end of file:

```
$line = fgets($fp, 2048);
if($line === false) break;
```

Fully working example:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen ("quotes.csv","r");
if (!$fp) {echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.</p>"; exit;}
?>
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Volume </th></tr>
<?php
$out = array();
$i=0;
while (!feof($fp)):
   $line = fgets($fp, 2048);
   if($line === false) break;
   $out[$i] = array($line);

   list ($ID, $Price, $StockDate, $StockTime, $Change, $DayHI, $DayLOW, $Volume) = explode(",", $out[$i][0]);


   echo "<tr><td>$ID</td> <td>$Price</td> <td>$StockDate </td><td>$StockTime</td> <td>$Change</td> <td>$DayHI</td> <td>$DayLOW</td> <td>$Volume</td></tr>";
   $i++;
endwhile;

?>
</table>
<?php


echo "<p>".$out[0][0]."</p>";
fclose($fp);
```

Last `echo` gave me my first string line from .csv.

Comment: Nope unfortunately I still get the offset errors :/

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\Assignment\Table.php on line 14

Comment: Ok, let me check other things.

Comment: Thank you my friend! :) I wish I was so much better at all this coding but I suppose we all have to start somewhere!

Comment: Have fun with programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making a single variable for the exploded values and check if the variable contains all the data

```
$temporal_var = explode(",", $out[$i][0]);
print_r($temporal_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have initialized the `$out` array? moreover for what i see you don't need the `$i` index since you can just call `$out[] = array($line);` to append an element to the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, using the native php CSV handler:

```
<?php 
// Set a list of headers
$ths[0] = 'ID';
$ths[1] = 'Price';
$ths[2] = 'StockDate';
$ths[3] = 'StockTime';
$ths[4] = 'Change';
$ths[5] = 'DayHI';
$ths[6] = 'DayLOW';
$ths[7] = 'Volume';

// Open the file with error handling
$fp = fopen('quotes.csv', 'r');
if( !$fp ) { die('<p>Unable to open remote file.</p>'); }
// Get the size
$fz = filesize('quotes.csv') + 1;
// Create a Data holder array
$fpData = array();
// While there is a line. Use native fgetcsv()
while ( $fpRow = fgetcsv( $fp, $fz, ',' ) ) {
    // For each element in the row we asign it to its header
    for ($i=0; $i < count($fpRow); $i++) { 
        $thisRow[ $ths[$i] ] = $fpRow[ $i ];
    }
    // Append to the Data array
    $fpData[] = $thisRow;
}
// Close the file
fclose($fp);
// Test the output
// print_r( $fpData );
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Get CVS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($ths as $thisField): ?>
                    <th><?php echo $thisField ?></th>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($fpData as $thisItem): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['ID'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['Price'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['StockDate'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['StockTime'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['Change'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['DayHI'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['DayLOW'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $thisItem['Volume'] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```